# Writing to the middle of a text file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```html
from __future__ import print_function
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
import xlrd
import sys

sys.stdout = open('C:/Users/Shane/Desktop/textfile.txt','w')
print ('')

# Open the workbook
file_location = "C:/Users/Shane/Desktop/MAIN_DATA.xls"
xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)

# List sheet names, and pull a sheet by name
#
sheet_names = xl_workbook.sheet_names()
#print('Sheet Names', sheet_names)

xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])

# Or grab the first sheet by index
#  (sheets are zero-indexed)
#
xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
#print ('Sheet name: %s' % xl_sheet.name)

# Pull the first row by index
#  (rows/columns are also zero-indexed)
#
row = xl_sheet.row(1)  # 1st row

# Print 1st row values and types
#
from xlrd.sheet import ctype_text

print('(Column #) type:value')
for idx, cell_obj in enumerate(row):
    cell_type_str = ctype_text.get(cell_obj.ctype, 'unknown type')
    print('(%s) %s %s' % (idx, cell_type_str, cell_obj.value))
```

So this is my code, I am trying to write to a text file from an excel spreadsheet using python and pycharm. The text file is created so I need to edit it and place the text from the excel file into around the middle of the text file. This code just prints the results to a blank text file, how can I write this code to the middle of an all ready made file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code so we know what isn't working for you.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with Excel.  It is "how do I print into the middle of a text file".  Please remove  the Excel stuff, and then we can help with writing into the middle of a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in python : you should first read your file you can maybe use panda :

```
import pandas as pd
TheFile = pd.read_excel(path + filename)
```

and then write in a new file : http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Send some code and we will be able to help you more specifically !

Comment: It has become obvious that the OP can read Excel files just fine - his problem is how to print into the middle of  a text file.

Comment: in this case you open the file and write on this file, in any place... depend how you open and construct it ....